# .click jquery function stops working after one use

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, display

I bumped into a problem with my .click jquery function. What I want to happen: When I press the button one div is supposed to display:none, and another one is supposed to display:block. This works the first time I press the button, but after that nothing happens.

Here is some code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#0").click(function(){
        $("#product_container2").css("display", "none");
        $("#product_container3").css("display", "none");
        $("#product_container1").css("display", "block");
    });
    $("#1").click(function() {
        $("#product_container1").css("display", "none");
        $("#product_container3").css("display", "none");
        $("#product_container2").css("display", "block");
    });
    $("#2").click(function(){
        $("#product_container1").css("display", "none");
        $("#product_container2").css("display", "none");
        $("#product_container3").css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

```html
<section id="product_container1" class="col-12 product_container"> 
 <h1 id="product-h1"> Produkter </h1>
 <hr style="width:90%; margin-left:5%"> 
 <div  class="product_info_container productx">
  <img src="bilder/dumleOriginal220.png" alt="Dumle" id="product1" class="product"></img>
  <h2> Dumle Original 220 g</h2>
   <p> Dumle brings out the twinkle in your eyes. The goofy sweet is a combination of soft chewy toffee and smooth Fazer Chocolate. The... </p>
   
  <div id="button"> <b> Visa produkt information </b> </div>

 <hr style="width:80%; margin-left:5%; margin-top:10px;"> 
 </div>
  <div id="buttons">
     <a href="#product_container1" id="0" class="mybutton myred">1</a>
     <a href="#product_container2" id="1" class="mybutton myblue">2</a>
     <a href="#" id="2" class="mybutton myblue">3</a>
</div>
</section>

<section id="product_container2" class="col-12 product_container"> 
 <h1 id="product-h1"> Produkter </h1>
 <hr style="width:90%; margin-left:5%"> 
 <div  class="product_info_container productx">
  <img src="bilder/dumleOriginal220.png" alt="Dumle" id="product1" class="product"></img>
  <h2> Dumle Original 220 g</h2>
   <p> Dumle brings out the twinkle in your eyes. The goofy sweet is a combination of soft chewy toffee and smooth Fazer Chocolate. The... </p>
   
  <div id="button"> <b> Visa produkt information </b> </div>

 <hr style="width:80%; margin-left:5%; margin-top:10px;"> 
 </div>
  <div id="buttons">
     <a href="#product_container1" id="0" class="mybutton myred">1</a>
     <a href="#product_container2" id="1" class="mybutton myblue">2</a>
     <a href="#" id="2" class="mybutton myblue">3</a>
</div>
</section>

<section id="product_container3" class="col-12 product_container"> 
 <h1 id="product-h1"> Produkter </h1>
 <hr style="width:90%; margin-left:5%"> 
 <div  class="product_info_container productx">
  <img src="bilder/dumleOriginal220.png" alt="Dumle" id="product1" class="product"></img>
  <h2> Dumle Original 220 g</h2>
   <p> Dumle brings out the twinkle in your eyes. The goofy sweet is a combination of soft chewy toffee and smooth Fazer Chocolate. The... </p>
   
  <div id="button"> <b> Visa produkt information </b> </div>

 <hr style="width:80%; margin-left:5%; margin-top:10px;"> 
 </div>
  <div id="buttons">
     <a href="#product_container1" id="0" class="mybutton myred">1</a>
     <a href="#product_container2" id="1" class="mybutton myblue">2</a>
     <a href="#" id="2" class="mybutton myblue">3</a>
</div>
</section>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can see is that you are using the same id tags for multiple different objects on the same page. If you use it at more than one place, use a class! You should never have more than one of the same id because you will be facing a lot of repeating problems...

Comment: Oh well. Changed the id's to class and the problem is fixed. This was something I was going to fix sometime, did not know it could cause problems like this. Thank you for your help, will remember this for future makings ;)

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<section id="product_container1" class="col-12 product_container"> 
<h1 id="product-h1"> Produkter 1</h1>
<hr style="width:90%; margin-left:5%"> 
<div  class="product_info_container productx">
    <img src="bilder/dumleOriginal220.png" alt="Dumle" id="product1" class="product">
<h2> Dumle Original 220 g</h2>
        <p> Dumle brings out the twinkle in your eyes. The goofy sweet is a combination of soft chewy toffee and smooth Fazer Chocolate. The... </p>

    <div id="button"> <b> Visa produkt information </b> </div>

<hr style="width:80%; margin-left:5%; margin-top:10px;"> 
</div>
</section>

<section id="product_container2" class="col-12 product_container"> 
<h1 id="product-h1"> Produkter 2</h1>
<hr style="width:90%; margin-left:5%"> 
<div  class="product_info_container productx">
    <img src="bilder/dumleOriginal220.png" alt="Dumle" id="product1" class="product">
    <h2> Dumle Original 220 g</h2>
        <p> Dumle brings out the twinkle in your eyes. The goofy sweet is a combination of           soft chewy toffee and smooth Fazer Chocolate. The... </p>

    <div id="button"> <b> Visa produkt information </b> </div>

<hr style="width:80%; margin-left:5%; margin-top:10px;"> 
</div>
</section>

<section id="product_contai`enter code here`ner3" class="col-12 product_container"> 
<h1 id="product-h1"> Produkter 3</h1>
<hr style="width:90%; margin-left:5%"> 
<div  class="product_info_container productx">
    <img src="bilder/dumleOriginal220.png" alt="Dumle" id="product1" class="product">
    <h2> Dumle Original 220 g</h2>
        <p> Dumle brings out the twinkle in your eyes. The goofy sweet is a combination of               soft chewy toffee and smooth Fazer Chocolate. The... </p>

    <div id="button"> <b> Visa produkt information </b> </div>

<hr style="width:80%; margin-left:5%; margin-top:10px;"> 
</div>

</section>
<div id="buttons">
   <a href="#product_container1" id="0"  class="mybutton myred">1</a>
   <a href="#product_container2" id="1" class="mybutton myblue">2</a>
   <a href="#" id="2"  class="mybutton myblue">3</a>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#0").click(function(){
    $("#product_container2").css("display", "none");
    $("#product_container3").css("display", "none");
    $("#product_container1").css("display", "block");
});
$("#1").click(function() {
    $("#product_container1").css("display", "none");
    $("#product_container3").css("display", "none");
    $("#product_container2").css("display", "block");
});
$("#2").click(function(){
    $("#product_container1").css("display", "none");
    $("#product_container2").css("display", "none");
    $("#product_container3").css("display", "block");
});
});

</script>
```